# Enable Coupon Code for Users If they Visit a specific page in the website

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, coupon

How to enable Coupon Code for Users If they Visit a specific page in Woo commerce website

Answer (score 0):

Implemented this by using the hook  [woocommerce_coupon_is_valid](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_coupon_is_valid/)

Thanks